# Custom domain templates with AngularJS

Tags: templates, angularjs

Can someone please advise me what is the best method to setup AngularJS with multiple templates?

I have a web application which has the same functionality across our white labelled customers but each customer has different templates.

I'm thinking that we simply setup a folder of templates and make the server-side pick the appropriate templates for each domain name.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how you have structured (or can structure) your templates. Three possible cases:

- **Aim to have the same client-side app for each user, but move all client-specific formatting to CSS.** In this case, your server would just server a different stylesheet for each client, which could adjust things like branding, logo etc.
- **Pass the client key through as a variable** (for example, assigned to `$rootScope`). This would allow you to do things like specific `ng-include` where appropriate, if your customisation per client is non-trivial.
- **Fully separated client-side app.** Serve a versioned client-side app depending on the client. This would be the best choice if you have major, significant differences in functionality per client. Would work if you have generic data endpoints (i.e. RESTful), that are non-client-specific. However, this would add major overhead in terms of testing, QA etc - so would recommend as a last option.

I would consider the above cases in descending priority - if possible, use only stylesheets, otherwise minor switches / template changes, or as a last case, a fully separated app.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I had the possible cases you listed in mind but was looking for validation as it's not your usual project. I agree, we will start with keeping all client-specific formatting in CSS but we may need to extend in scenarios where additional front-end functionality is needed. The data is transferred using a RESTful API and most of the customer data is the same.